# If you cd to a different user's home and run an apt install command does that do anything special?

Tags: apt, software-installation, cd-command

If you cd to a different user's home and run an apt install command does that do anything special?

I know, I know, this sounds dumb. My base instinct is to say : "No, obviously!"

but then I saw this : https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD

as part of the install process they have us create it's new user and then cd into his home.

I'm wondering if cdin'g into his home before installing can be skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instinct is correct. It can be skipped for the `apt-get` command. The current working directory has no influence on the installation.

But be aware, that the following command

```
ln -s /usr/games/steamcmd steamcmd
```

creates a symlink in the current working directory. So if you want it to be in the `steam` users home, then it needs to change to

```
ln -s /usr/games/steamcmd /home/steam/steamcmd
```

That is maybe, why they added this step.